# How to noindex Custom post tag in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a site which is displaying post tag in different format rather than the WP default tag format

WP default post tag url:

> abc.com/tag/item

Where i have my tags in my website is like that

> abc.com/post_tag/item

Tags in my site

> https://readnational.com/post_tag/barbary-lion/

It display post_tag instead of tag

So i don't see the noindex option for this custom post tag in the yoast or rank math to noindex them all,

Kindly help me to add piece of code in function.php to noindex all tag links of my site

https://readnational.com/post_tag/barbary-lion/
https://readnational.com/post_tag/cow/

So for all tags

I hope someone would help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In robots.txt add:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /post_tag
```

Alternative in your functions.php:

```
function no_index_cpt()
{   $taxonomy = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    if ($taxonomy  === 'post-tag') {
        print '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'no_index_cpt');
```

Comment: I know it already but that is not what i want, i want to add noindex to these pages, like if(post_tag)add noindex to the page

Comment: I know to block these pages via robots but i dont do it in that way i want to someone add php code to add noindex

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative, try it.

Comment: The code is not working i have put the code in the function.php file but it does not work, you can view the source code and check the robot meta tag it is still follow, index https://readnational.com/post_tag/barbary-lion/

Comment: the url https://readnational.com/post_tag/barbary-lion/ redirects to homepage

Comment: i solved the problem there was some internal issue in the theme, Thanks